# How to change background color of single cell in a windows.forms.datagrid?

Tags: winforms, datagrid, coding-style, cell

I desperately try to figure how to change the background color of a single cell in a winforms dataGridView. I have two columns: if i change content in the second column, i want the cell in the first column of this row to change the background accordingly.

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex != 0 || e.RowIndex == -1)
            return;
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "Red")
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        else
            e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex != 1 || e.RowIndex == -1)
            return;
        // dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0]. ???
    }
```

The first event handler sets the backColor of the cells in the first column if they are painted. The second event handler should tell the first cell to paint if the value is changed. If i change the columns width it paints the correct color, so the first handler does the work. But how to trigger the cell painting?

Thanx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have thought that the edit would have triggered a repaint, but if that event isn't being run after the edit then you should be able to force the issue with something like:

```
dataGridView1.InvalidateCell(e.RowIndex, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is the bad hack:

If i insert

```
var x = dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle = null;
dataGridView1.Columns[0].DefaultCellStyle = x;
```

in the CellValueChanged event handler, the whole first column is repainted. So my cell is repainted as well. But that't dirty, isnt't it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new cell style object, set it to the color you want and then apply it to the current cell.

private DataGridViewCellStyle CellStyleGreenBackgnd;

CellStyleGreenBackgnd.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;

dataGridView.CurrentCell.Style.ApplyStyle(CellStyleGreenBackgnd);

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
dataGridView1.Rows[indexhere].Cells[indexhere].Style.ForeColor = Color.Yellow;
```